# Since when netcat/socat is NOT a "software tools commonly used by programmers"?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

I asked a reproducible & clear question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15606087/41948)

So let's talk about the FAQ:

> What kind of questions can I ask here?
>   - software tools commonly used by programmers
>   You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

My question involves problems with features of `socat`, according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat)

> `Socat` is a more complex variant of netcat. It is larger and more flexible and has more options that must be configured for a given task.

Can someone please explain why is my question considered off topic and what I could do to help it become on-topic?

For reference, look at the "**Related**" right sidebar, there's gazillion of sctp or Homebrew questions similar to mine.

Comment: I can easily see questions about *using* them as on-topic, but basic compilation and installation questions are pushing it.

Comment: @Charles Pardon my English, did you mean compilation/installation questions are too basic level for sites like stackoverflow, I mean, really? You never searched for any single compilation errors on the Internet and hopefully someone asked the same question and solved by helpful people?

Comment: It's not too *basic*, it's just not something that's on-topic.

Comment: Hi est, I edited this a bit to make it sound like less of a rant. The MSO community here generally tries to be objective and helpful, and the first sentence of a post asking for help with a closed post can set the tone for how people react. Hope this helps in case you have a future question. Good luck! :)

Comment: @jmort253 Thanks for the edit man. MSO help me a lot this time as well as in the past.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is possibly a borderline one. It's not asking about an actual programming problem, which is where some people may have been tripped up. This doesn't mean it's off-topic, but there are things that you can do to help ensure posts like this get reopened and stay reopened.

First, it would help if you could edit into your post whether or not there were online resources you found that gave instructions on how to solve these issues. If you didn't find anything helpful, listing this in your post would ensure answerers don't tell you things you already know, or that close voters don't think that your question is too broad to be answered without seeing a comment under their answer that says "No! I tried that already and it didn't work!"

If there were no online resources found that help with this, and you *did* search, then you should edit that into your post to clarify.

Saying what you know, what you've tried, and what resources you found not only helps you understand the problem better, but it creates a question that has a greater chance of not only being answered by the community but also helping future visitors who also have the same or a similar problem. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the info buddy. I am trying very hard to work on a hobby program which involves sctp, to learn it I have to get debug & testing tools working first right? Until then I might have sctp programming problems.

Comment: Absolutely, getting tools working is indeed step 1, which makes me personally think your question isn't off-topic, it just needs a little more TLC and clarity to help others visualize your goals. Looks like you made some good edits, and it looks like some people helped reopen your post. Good luck getting your solution! :)